# Using cordova for website app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'll try to make a my website app, in relaty I need a top menu with some features and on the main frame I would like to see the web site, BUT I have to pharse the code for:

- Create the menu in top menu with some other features
- Take only the part that interests me

I don't care if I loose the original page format, I would like to parshe the original html code and work it

I tried InAppBrowser but it open the browser....I look some JSON translating but it's just for fun, I would not like spend 30$ :(
The site is made in joomla

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova isn't designed to directly load content from a website as a page.

You may be able to build a simple jQuery AJAX request for each page you want to show and then extract pieces of the resulting document.

Alternately, you could use a back-end plugin for Joomla that allows you to interface with the data from the website and then display it in an app you build using Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cordova to create a webview based app that builds the menu HTML / CSS / JS in the app on the device then for each section in the menu renders some of the content from your website inside another div in your webview and apply styles to that locally in the Cordova app.  This would however make your app dependent the network to get to your website so you may also wish to consider caching content in the Cordova app for a period of time.

Ideally you would use Ajax requests back to the Joomla CMS and get the content through a JSON or XML (if you must) API then render it in the Cordova client using the Javascript framework of your choice.